# How does Spark Structured Streaming determine an event has arrived late?

Tags: apache-spark

I read through the spark structured streaming documentation and I wonder how does spark structured streaming determine an event has arrived late? Does it compare the event-time with the processing time?

[image]

Taking the above picture as an example Is the bold right arrow line "Time" represent processing time? If so

1) where does this processing time come from? since its streaming Is it assuming someone is likely using an upstream source that has processing timestamp in it or spark adds a processing timestamp field? For example, when reading messages from Kafka we do something like

```
Dataset<Row> kafkadf = spark.readStream().forma("kafka").load()
```

This dataframe has timestamp column by default which I am assuming is the processing time. correct? If so, Does Kafka or Spark add this timestamp?

2) I can see there is a time comparison between bold right arrow line and time in the message. And is that how spark determines an event is late?

Answer (score 1):

This document from databricks explains it pretty clearly:
https://databricks.com/blog/2017/05/08/event-time-aggregation-watermarking-apache-sparks-structured-streaming.html

Basically it comes down to the watermark (late data threshold) and the order in which data records arrive. Processing time does not play into it at all. You set a watermark on the column representing your event time. If a record R1 with event time T1 arrives after a record R2 with event time T2 has already been seen, and T2 > T1 + Threshold, then R1 will be discarded.

For example, suppose T1 = 09:00, T2 = 10:00, Threshold = 61 min. If a record R1 with event time T1 arrives before a record R2 with event time T2 then R1 is included in calculations. If R1 arrives after R2 then R1 is still included in calculations because T2 < T1 + Threshold.

Now suppose Threshold = 59 min. If R1 arrives before R2 then R1 is included in calculations. If R1 arrives after R2, then R1 is discarded because we've already seen a record with event time T2 and T2 > T1 + Threshold.

Answer (score 0):

Processing time of individual job (one `RDD` of the `DStream`) is what dictate the processing time in general. It is not when the actual processing of that RDD happen but when the `RDD` job was allocated to be processed.
In order to clearly understand what the above statement means, create a spark streaming application where batch time = `60 seconds` and make sure the batch takes `2 minute`. Eventually you will see that a job is allocated to be processed at a time but has not been picked up because the previous job has not finished.

Next:
Out of order data can be dealt two different ways.

1. Create a `High water mark`.

It is explained in the same spark user guide page you got your picture.

It is easy to understand where we have a `key`, `value` pair where key is the `timestamp`. Setting `.withWatermark("timestamp", "10 minutes")` we are essentially saying that if I have received a message for `10 AM` then I will allow messages little older than that`(Upto 9.50AM)`. Any message older than that gets dropped.

2. The other way out of order data can be handled is with in the `mapGroupsWithState` or `mapWithState` function. 
   Here you can decide what to do when you get bunch of values for a key. Drop anything before time X or go even fancier than that. (Like if it is data from A then allow 20 minutes delay, for the rest allow 30 minutes delay etc...)

Comment: Dear Downvoter, it would be great if you will say what is wrong when you down vote - then user can edit and improve quality :)